# Sharing a Google Calendar via Google's APIs

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

I am able to make a Google calendar in my account though Google Calendar's APIs, but I want to share it as well. Is there a way to do this programatically?

Answer (score 4):

From Google Calendar API documentation: [Sharing calendars](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_java.html#SharingACalendar)

Comment: i used it but not able to share my calender

Comment: The API works. Now if you don't show us how you're trying to use it, we can't help you much.

Comment: that link is invalid!

Answer (score 0):

try this function, see if it works. This will make the calendar shared inside your domain wide.

```
function updateACLRole($cal_id, $USER) {
    $data = "<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:gAcl='http://schemas.google.com/acl/2007' >
      <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind'
        term='http://schemas.google.com/acl/2007#accessRule'/>
      <gAcl:scope type='domain' value='".$this->CONSUMER_KEY."' ></gAcl:scope>
      <gAcl:role value='http://schemas.google.com/gCal/2005#read'></gAcl:role>
    </entry>";
    $uri = 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/' . $cal_id . '/acl/full/domain%3A'.$this->CONSUMER_KEY.'?xoauth_requestor_id=' . urlencode($USER);

    $result = $this->gdataCal->put($data, $uri);

}
```